# Media Controller never show on Video View

Tags: android, media, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview, mediacontroller

I searched many topics with many same answers,

but looks like not worked for me & with many people also.

`Create Custom Media Controller`

```
public class CcMediaController extends MediaController {

ImageButton mCCBtn;
Context mContext;
AlertDialog mLangDialog;

public CcMediaController(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public void setAnchorView(View view) {
    super.setAnchorView(view);

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    frameParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT|Gravity.TOP;

    View v = makeCCView();
    addView(v, frameParams);
}

private View makeCCView() {
    mCCBtn = new ImageButton(mContext);
    mCCBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.abc_ab_bottom_solid_dark_holo);

    mCCBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
            builder.setSingleChoiceItems(R.array.array, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //Save Preference and Dismiss the Dialog here
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Which ::: "+which, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            });
            mLangDialog = builder.create();
            mLangDialog.show();
        }
    });

    return mCCBtn;
}
}
```

`Put Custom Media Controller into Video View by using setAnchorView()`

```
CcMediaController mMc = new CcMediaController(this);

// FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FameLayout.LayoutParams(
// FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
// FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
// lp.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
// mMc.setLayoutParams(lp);
//
// ((ViewGroup) mMc.getParent()).removeView(mMc);
//
// (new VideoControllerView(this)).addView(mMc);

        // set play video view dialog details photo
        mMc.setAnchorView(mVvPlayVideoInDetail);
        mMc.setMediaPlayer(mVvPlayVideoInDetail);

        mVvPlayVideoInDetail.requestFocus();
        mVvPlayVideoInDetail.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        mVvPlayVideoInDetail.setMediaController(mMc);
        mVvPlayVideoInDetail.setZOrderOnTop(true);
```

`VideoView.xml`

```
<VideoView
            android:alpha="0.5"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:id="@+id/vv_play_video_dialog_detail"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="visible"
            />
```

I showed Video View as one part of dialog with the height = 240dp, not in Full screen.

Still not worked,

Please help me how to `show Media Controller on Video View correctly`,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to call  `setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);` 
this is due to `setzorderontop(true)` no view can be shown on video view so calling `setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);` will override `setzorderontop(true)`